# jQuery datepicker specific date disable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have code to disable specific dates on jquery datepicker. code runs fine on my local environment but not working on GoDaddy windows hosting

```
var disableddates  = result;  //result is array of dates ["1/7/2018","1/8/2018","1/9/2018"]
$("#txtFromdate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay : DisableSpecificDates
});
$("#txtTodate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay : DisableSpecificDates 
});

function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
    console.log(string);  //this string return with leading zero 01/07/2018...
    return [disableddates.indexOf(string) == -1];
}
```

This code run fine on local but when making it live it is not disabling specific dates in jQuery datepicker.

Comment: Any `errors` in `console`?

Comment: This would not be related to JavaScript. JavaScript and jQuery are Client Side scripting languanges; hence, they should run the same locally and on a remote server. The same code is running in your browser. I suspect your `result` array is populated by a server side script and that is provided unexpected results. Also if you're String is different in any way, `01/01/18` versus `1/1/2018`, you're going to have difficulties. Would advise using Date versus String for comparison.

Comment: @MUT no it is clear there is no error

Comment: @Twisty Yes result array is populated at server side it is in string format.  but on localhost string is in same format like 01/01/2018, but after making it live it changes to 1/1/2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to format the date if it's already in a date format. For example, if `result` contains an array date like `"1/7/2018"`, you can create a Date object from this:

```
var newDate = new Date(result[0]);
```

With this in mind, you can easily make and manipulate a Date. DatePicker passes a Date object to the function too. Here is a solution you might try:

```js
$(function() {
  var disableddates = ["1/7/2018", "1/8/2018", "1/9/2018"];

  $("#txtFromdate, #txtTodate").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy"
  });

  $("#txtFromdate").change(function() {
    $("#txtTodate").datepicker("option", "minDate", $(this).val());
  });

  function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
    var result = [true];
    $.each(disableddates, function(k, v) {
      var exclude = new Date(v).toString();
      var today = date.toString();
      if (exclude == today) {
        console.log("Match", exclude, today);
        result = [false];
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  width: 60px;
}

input {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<label for="txtFromdate">From:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtFromdate" />
<label for="txtTodate">To:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtTodate" />
```

My Testing done here: https://jsfiddle.net/95t81vzq/3/

Hope that helps.